# SWI-PROLOG structure

Tags: prolog

```
    family(
person(jim, tan, male, hobby([fishing, badminton, swim]), dob(2, 1, 1962)),
person(ann, tan, female, hobby([cooking, badminton]), dob(4,9, 1968)),
[person(ham, tan, male, hobby([fishing, football, swim]), dob(18,5, 1984)),
 person(wan, tan, female, hobby([reading, music, swim]), dob(25, 12, 1986))]
). % Tan's Family(Husband, Wife, [Life_of_Children]).

family(
   person(john, lim, male, hobby([music, reading, watchingTV]), dob(28, 10, 1972)),
   person(belle, lim, female, hobby([music, reading, badminton]), dob(9, 4, 1974)),
   [person(sophia, lim, female, hobby([reading, traveling]), dob(8, 8, 1985)),
person(annie, lim, female, hobby([badminton, volleyball, games]), dob(9, 6, 1987)),
person(william, lim, male, hobby([badminton, swim, games]), dob(10, 7, 1988))]
  ).

% Lim's Family

husband(X):-    %X is a husband if
    family(X, _, _).    %X is the 1st member in family
wife(X):-   %X is a wife if
    family(_, X, _).    %X is a 2nd member in family
child(X):-  %X is a child if
    family(_, _, ChildList),    %X is a member in ChildList
    member(X, ChildList).

family_member(X):-  % X is a family member if
    husband(X); % X is a husband, or
    wife(X);    % X is a wife, or
    child(X).   % X is a child.
gender(Person, X):- % The gender of Person is X if
    Person = person(_, _, X, _,_).  % X matched with the 3rd element in person
interest(Person, X):-   % Interest of Person is X if
    Person = person(_, _, _, hobby(HobbyList),_),
    member(X, HobbyList).   % X is a member in HobbyList.
firstname(X, FirstName):-
    X = person(FirstName, _, _, _, _).
lastname(X, LastName):-
    X = person(_, LastName, _, _, _).
birthday(X, dob(Day, Month, Year)):-
    X = person(_, _, _, _, dob(Day, Month, Year)).
yob(X, Year):-
    X = person(_, _, _, _, dob(_, _, Year)).

father(Father, Child).

brother(Child1, Child2):-
    child(_),
    lastname(Child1, LastName1),
    lastname(Child2, LastName2),
    LastName1 = LastName2.
```

how can i check the brother/2 Child1 and Child2 are from same family? i don't think my one is correct. and how to display in SWI-Prolog for finding all brothers from all families? i will very appreciate for the helps :)

Comment: One thing not quite right: you are missing a `person` predicate. In your listing, `person` is part of another structure, so `person(.)` won't instantiate without a predicate.

Comment: the person is work fine so far. :/ since this is practical question provided. LOL

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you didn't show all of your code. I tried it quickly in swi prolog and it said it was not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `Child1` and `Child2` are `person` structures? If so, then this should do it using your current structures:

```
brother(Child1, Child2) :-
    Child1 = person(_, _, male, _, _),  % verify that they're male (brother)
    Child2 = person(_, _, male, _, _),
    family(_, _, Siblings),             % Check to see if they are siblings in the same family
    member(Child1, Siblings),
    member(Child2, Siblings),
    Child1 \= Child2.
```

This will verify two brothers. If it means just one of them is a brother then:

```
brother(Child1, Child2) :-
    (  % verify that one is male (brother)
       Child1 = person(_, _, male, _, _)
     ; Child2 = person(_, _, male, _, _)
    ),
    family(_, _, Siblings),              % Check to see if they are siblings in the same family
    member(Child1, Siblings),
    member(Child2, Siblings),
    Child1 \= Child2.
```

Comment: i think the practical question mess up already.. the brother predicate i think should be means find all of the brother and sister from all families.

Comment: and the result keep coming with Child1 = Child2, Child2 = xxxx. why? @@

Comment: @JackWong it's quite trivial to abstract out the gender and add a condition that Child1 `\=` Child2. Try it.

Comment: @JackWong, yes, sorry I neglected to add the Child1 \= Child2 condition. Thank you, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

this could work...

```
brother(Child1, Child2):-
    child(Child1), gender(Child1, male),
    child(Child2),
    Child1 \= Child2,
    lastname(Child1, LastName),
    lastname(Child2, LastName).
```

but the approach 'object oriented' you're using will not scale very well, because Prolog is based on a *relational* data model.

Comment: Do you need a `gender(Child2, male)`? I was assuming that they were both brothers, but perhaps that wasn't clear from the OPs question.

Comment: I don't know enough about English, isn't a brother a *male* ?

Comment: Cute. I meant to say, "Don't" you need a `gender(Child2, male)`? I.e., will your `brother` predicate succeed if Child2 is female? It's just a question.

Comment: Yes, I tested enumerating with `?-brother(X,Y).` I got `X=person(william,...), Y=person(sophia,...)`. Anyway, the question is underspecified.

Comment: OK. When I read the OP's question, I thought he wanted it to validate 2x brothers. That's why I asked. My misunderstanding of what the OP wanted.

Comment: i also asked my tutor. now waiting for her reply. but i assume this is brother and sister relationship. :) i try first.

Comment: i think that's no need gender anymore since we are assuming there is brother and sister relationship?

Comment: brother(Child1, Child2):-
 family(_, _, Child),
 member(Child1, Child),
 member(Child2, Child),
 Child1 \= Child2.
i am using work fine but there's a problem
C1 = william, C2 = sophia;
C1 = sophia, C2 = william.

Comment: to break symmetry, use @< instead if \=

Comment: @< what is this meaning actually? tutor haven't cover this yet. :(
anyway, after i replace \= with @< is all work fine already. thanks CapelliC

Comment: it's the 'general' comparison operator. < works only for numbers.